# using pace loading progress bar in asp.net webform

Tags: webforms, pace

i use the following code in my asp.net web form for display pace progress bar. but it count until 99 percent and then stop. it works with html page but not aspx pages. can any body help me?

```
<head runat="server">
<title></title>

<link href="pace-theme-big-counter.css" rel="stylesheet" />
 <script src="pace.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>

</div>
</form>


</body>
```